# apache 2.4 virtual host brings me to "Index of /"

Tags: ssl-certificate, virtualhost, indexof, self-signed, apache2.4

i followed the following instructions: [virtual host](https://www.maketecheasier.com/name-based-virtualhost-apache/), [https](https://www.maketecheasier.com/apache-server-ssl-support/).

As i use a DynDNS for my locas hosted webside, my final `000-default.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName www.mydomain.dyndns.xx
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.dyndns.xx/
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.key

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www.virtualhost1.com_error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www.virtualhost1.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I additionaly configured in `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` the follwoing:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mydomain.dyndns.xx>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and in the `/etx/host`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi

192.168.x.x     www.mydomain.dyndns.xx
```

when i try to open the URL of the page it desplays me the "Indes of /" on Port 80, when i klick on those files, i get the http:// mydomain.dyndns.xx/mydomain.dyndns.xx.index.php

if i call the https:// then i get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on my browser.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `000-defualt.conf`file looks perfectly file . Although when using SSL certificates make sure to make the following changes :

**EDIT PORTS.CONF FILE**

Edit your `ports.conf` file and add the following line :

```
    Listen 192.168.x.x:443
```

This tells the apache to listen to incoming connections from the specified Ip : port 443

**TESTING CONFIG ON LOCALHOST**

You can test the config on your system first by making the following entry in `/etc/hosts` file:

```
    127.0.0.x    www.mydomain.dyndns.xx
```

And adding the following to `ports.conf` file:

```
    Listen 127.0.0.x:443
```

Make sure to comment out `192.168.x.x    www.mydomain.dyndns.xx` entry in `ports.conf` file before testing the config

**ENABLE MOD_SSL**

Enable `mod_ssl` by issuing the following command:

```
    sudo a2enmod ssl
```

**RESTART APACHE**

Restart apache2 : `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

In your browser point to your domain name : `https://www.mydomain.dyndns.xx`